# How would I implement a metadata provider/export function in OpenSAML?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

Using OpenSAML, I'd like to provide the ability to either (1) export my metadata for a given federation to a file, or (2) provide a URL that a potential federation partner can visit to obtain the metadata for the federation I've set up for them. I know that both of these can be done, but I'm at a loss to find documentation or information about how to do this using the OpenSAML libraries.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, there is nothing in the existing OpenSAML libraries to perform metadata export. This functionality must be written manually.

Comment: As with most high level functionality when working with OpenSAML =)